# Try to import a database with sql script file

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to import a small database from [this website](https://postgrespro.com/docs/postgrespro/12/demodb-bookings-installation) into Postgresql. I tried the restore button and choosed the sql file, but it fails with the below message

> pg_restore: Error: Input file is apparently a dump in text format. Please use psql.

Then I tried to run the sql command from the file in the sql query, but it fails with the message:

> invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8".

Does anybody know how I can import it?

Thx in advance!

Comment: You need to restore the dump with `psql`, not with pgAdmin.

Comment: I tried to use this command in psql: pg_dump database_name > demo-small-en-20170815

Comment: but nothing happened. In which folder the sql.-file need to be?

Comment: `psql` is a program, not an RDBMS. You have to restore the dump file using that program. Perhaps you should read some documentation...